# JQuery Masonry: Images stacking until page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-masonry

This is most likely a duplicate, but I do not know JQuery and have just been copying/pasting code to get to this point. I do not understand why my images are stacked until I do a page resize. Here is my code:

```
$ ->
  $('things').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#things').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

Comment: This is [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org) + jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not only jQuery but jQuery + [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org).

Here a "translation" of your code in javascript (with jQuery framework) :

```
$(function() {
  $('things').imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('#things').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      isFitWidth: true
    });
  });
});
```

In coffeescript `->` mean `function` (for anonymous function).